# mxPoint relative to what?

Tags: xml, mxgraph

I am trying to convert from an draw.io based diagram to another diagram type with absolute coordinates.

In mxGraph the coordinates are relative, so the shapes are relative positioned to their container vertex. But to what are the points of an edge (a connection between two shapes) relative?

```xml
<mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
    <Array as="points">
        <mxPoint x="210" y="100"/>
        <mxPoint x="210" y="100"/>
     </Array>
     <mxPoint x="170" y="30" as="sourcePoint"/>
     <mxPoint x="310" y="30" as="targetPoint"/>
</mxGeometry>
```